# EMF file has transparent background instead of a white one

Tags: inkscape

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I am a programmer who needs to put an `EMF` file on a certain place in my applications main window. My clients didn't give me the file I need, but I was given the `PNG` image of it. This is a problem for me, since I am a complete beginner in the area of graphics design/editing. I have never used Photoshop or any similar program.

After using some free online tools for sharpening and resizing of the picture, I was able to get an acceptable quality.

I have stumbled upon [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNIHO3eNcqw) tutorial, during my search for a way to convert that "enhanced" `PNG` to `EMF`.

I have made a print-screen of the desktop, cropped the logo from the tutorial with Paint, and tried to repeat what I saw there. I was successful. I have tried to do the same for the picture sent to me, and it seems that it worked. All I needed to do is to save it as an `EMF`, which I did.

### PROBLEM:

When I use the `EMF` file in my code, everything that was white in the original `PNG` is transparent, yet white color should have remained in some parts of the picture.

To illustrate exactly what kind of a problem I am facing with, I have uploaded `PNG` file, and the resulting `EMF` file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/png2emf).

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:

I know that Inkscape has white color as transparent by default, so I have tried to alter it in `Document properties` to yellow, and to try the same method described above again in hope of success. Unfortunately, that did not help.

I have tried to find the similar question here, but search engine shows nothing. I have tried finding solution on the Internet, but it seems that nobody saves images made in Inkscape as `EMF`, but as `SVG` which is expected.

The only thing left for me, in my humble opinion, is to "insert" white color where necessary using text editor (like Notepad) , but I do not know how to do it, since I do not know `SVG` standard.

### QUESTION:

What can I do to make the `EMF` file look as the `PNG` submitted above?

Comment: You could just draw a white shape which follows the outline shape, move it to the back, then save. For what it's worth, opening that EMF file in Illustrator shows an **unearthly amount of anchor points**.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Being a beginner, I find it difficult to implement your suggestions. Perhaps you could provide links/books/tutorials to help me get started? Regards.

Comment: You might start with the basic Inkscape documentation: http://inkscape.org/doc/shapes/tutorial-shapes.html

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and report my results as soon as possible ( it may take a while, since I am busy with the programming other parts of the UI as well ). Thank you. Regards.